# Explanation for calling the outer function within its own code block

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, nodes

I'm new to JavaScript. I found this example in a book. The chapter discusses node types but doesn't thoroughly explain the example. I need assistance in understanding what occurs in the while loop within the testing function.

My understanding is that the while loop ends when a parent element ceases to have a child element. But does the program wait until no child elements can be found, which allows it to console log node? I don't know what is the order of sequence.

I'd appreciate if someone can explain to me in layman terms how this function operates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript</h1>
<h2><img><a><span></span></a></img></h2>
<h3><img></img></h3>

<script>
function testing(node){
    if(node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE){
        console.log(node.tagName);
        node = node.firstChild;
        
        while(node){
            testing(node)
            node = node.nextSibling;
            console.log(node);
        }
    }
}


let boom = document.querySelector("h2");
testing(boom);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is known as "recursion". You'll find many more examples, also in different languages, with explanations on the web, many with simpler code.

Comment: It's recursion, the best example to understand it is `factorial calculation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is usually used to simplify the problem; here it's the opposite.

The simplest way to understand this is to actually walk through the function.

**1.**
Start with `h2` as the first `node`, check if it's a `node` and log it.

**2.**
Assign the first child of `node(h2 currently)`, which is `img` to `node`.

**3.**
Check `node` in the while condition, if yes: call testing with `node(img)`, log `img` .

(# here we enter recursion)

#**4.**
Assign to `node` the first child of `img`, which is `null`,
so we omit the loop.

(#here we quit recursision and `node` contains `img`)

**5.**
Assign the next sibling of `img` which is `a`, log `<a><span></span><a>`.

**6.**
Check `node` in the while condition, if yes: call testing with `node(a)`.

(# here we enter recursion)

#**7** log tagname of `a` which is `A`, get the first child of `a`, which is `span`.

(## here we enter recursion)

##**8**
log tagname os `span` which is `SPAN`, assign first child of `span` to `node` which is `null`.

##**9** Check `node` in the while condition, if false: we are back at `node` with `span`.

##**10**
Assign the next sibling of `span` which is null, log it.

##**11**
Check `node` in the while condition, if false: we go back to the recursive call with `a`.

(##here we quit recursision)

#**12**
Assign next sibling of `a` to node, which is null.

#**13**
Check `node` in the while condition, if false: quit recursive call with 'a'.

(#here we quit recursision)

**14**
End the function call.

#(means the level of recursion)

Hope this helps, but ideally you should debug the code by yourself and go through it step by step.

You can do this by splitting the file into index.html and index.js, write `<script src="index.js"></script>` in index.html and walk through by putting a breakpoint on the `let boom...` line in the chrome debugger.

Comment: Thank you for going through each step. Seriously, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The script is running a recursion function iterating through the HTML nodes.
It drills down the DOM structure until it it can find no child elements and then will go through a list of siblings until it can find another child element (through the recursive function) and repeat on finding more child elements
the output is

```
H2       (First element)
IMG      (Child of H2)
<a>​…​</a>​ (Sibling of IMG)
A        (First element of sibling)
SPAN     (Child of A)
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

The nulls at the end are the result of the recursion exit condition being met and printing out that there is no valid element 
Initially its confusing because IMG looks like it has a child () but the HTML is rendered like so

```
<h2>
    <img>
    <a>
       <span>
       </span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

To get a full understanding I would look at what recursion is 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/ 
and read up on what the node elements are to get a understanding of what the script itself is running https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helped a lot. I'm going to check more about recursion.